# I have one select list, which should send data with a few forms

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have that kind of site: (set of forms)

```
                <select id="group_dropdown" name="selectinput">
                <option value=0>all</option>
                <option value=1>1 option</option>
                <option value=2>2 option</option>
                </select>               


        <form method="post" class="form-inline" id="form11">
           <input type="text" name="1forminput" placeholder="0"></label>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success ml40" >save</button>
        </form>

        <form method="post" class="form-inline" id="form22">
           <input type="text" name="forminput" placeholder="0"></label>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success ml40" >save</button>
        </form>
```

I want to send data from this select (which is "mutual" for both of these forms) when any of these forms is sent (like an additional field withind sending form).
Is it a simple solution for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add hidden inputs, and have valid markup with starting label tags etc

```
<select id="group_dropdown" name="selectinput">
    <option value="0">all</option>
    <option value="1">1 option</option>
    <option value="2">2 option</option>
</select>

<form method="post" class="form-inline" id="form11">
    <label>
        <input type="text" name="1forminput" placeholder="0" />
        <input type="hidden" name="select_value" />
    </label>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success ml40">save</button>
</form>

<form method="post" class="form-inline" id="form22">
    <label>
        <input type="text" name="forminput" placeholder="0" />
        <input type="hidden" name="select_value" />
    </label>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success ml40">save</button>
</form>
```

Then fill in the hidden inputs when the select's value changes:

```
$('#group_dropdown').on('change', function() {
    $('[name="select_value"]').val(this.value);
}).trigger('change');
```

And the select's value will be sent with both forms when they are submitted, and accessed like:

```
$_POST['select_value'];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add a new parameter after serializing your form like this:

```
$('#form11').submit(function(){
   $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : 'url',
        data : $('#form11').serialize() + "&select="+$('#group_dropdown').val()  
    }).done(function( data ) {
       //callback
    });
   return false;
  });
```